# How to convert percentages into a timeseries index?

Tags: python, time-series, percentage

I have a time series of annual returns.

I want to convert the percentages to an index.

For e.g. total return time series shows annual returns. I would like it to see it as

1998-12-31   100

1999-12-31.  111.6507

2000-12-31.  125.55

...
....

Many thanks

date    total_return

1999-12-31  0.116507

2000-12-31  0.124500

2001-12-31  0.067565

2002-12-31  0.062774

2003-12-31  0.103384

2004-12-31  0.130776

2005-12-31  0.189867

2006-12-31  0.145452

2007-12-31  0.132526

2008-12-31  -0.079470

2009-12-31  -0.191446

2010-12-31  0.133377

2011-12-31  0.139314

2012-12-31  0.103205

2013-12-31  0.111638

2014-12-31  0.117227

2015-12-31  0.120510

2016-12-31  0.077795

2017-12-31  0.067697

2018-12-31  0.071384

2019-12-31  0.061313

Comment: What's the format of the current data? A string? A list?

Comment: It's numeric data. The annual rate of change. I would like to see it in an index. For e.g. it is 11.6%, 12.45%... I would like to see 100, 111.6, 124...

Comment: it's not clear what you want you should elaborate on your problem and explain it clearly.